# Insert SQL statements via command line without reopening connection to remote database

Tags: database, postgresql, shell, connection, psql

I have a large amount of data files to process and to be stored in the remote database. Each line of a data file represents a row in the database, but must be formatted before inserting into the database.

My first solution was to process data files by writing bash scripts and produce SQL data files, and then import the dump SQL files into the database. This solution seems to be too slow and as you can see involves an extra step of creating intermediary SQL file.

My second solution was to write bash scripts that while processing each line of the data file, creates and `INSERT INTO ...` statement and sends the SQL statement to the remote database:

`echo sql_statement | psql -h remote_server -U username -d database`

i.e. does not create SQL file. This solution, however, has one major issue that I am searching an advice on:
**Each time I have to reconnect to the remote database to insert one single row.**

Is there a way to connect to the remote database, stay connected and then "pipe" or "send" the insert-SQL-statement without creating a huge SQL file?

Comment: How much data are you processing? I would suggest to create the SQL file gzip and transfer to remote server and execute it there. That should def. be much faster than the process you are using currently

Comment: Are you concerned about harddisk usage? Otherwise I cannot see a difference between echoing the statements to a single file which is then run by psql and echoing each statement directly to psql in terms of complexity. You'll **have** to create an INSERT statement eventually.

Comment: My answer is very late, but I think it deals with the problem much more compactly/simply than the other one. Please take a look if you get the chance - thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Answer to your **actual question**

**Yes**. You can use a [named pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) instead of creating a file. Consider the following demo.

Create a schema `x` in my database `event` for testing:

```
-- DROP SCHEMA x CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA x;
CREATE TABLE x.x (id int, a text);
```

Create a named pipe (fifo) from the shell like this:

```sh
postgres@db:~$ mkfifo --mode=0666 /tmp/myPipe
```

Either **1)** call the SQL command `COPY` using a named pipe **on the server**:

```
postgres@db:~$ psql event -p5433 -c "COPY x.x FROM '/tmp/myPipe'"
```

This will acquire an **exclusive lock** on the table `x.x` in the database. The connection stays open until the fifo gets data. Be careful not to leave this open for too long! You can call this *after* you have filled the pipe to minimize blocking time. You can chose the sequence of events. The command executes as soon as two processes bind to the pipe. The first waits for the second.

Or **2)** you can execute SQL from the pipe **on the client**:

```
postgres@db:~$ psql event -p5433 -f /tmp/myPipe
```

This is better suited for your case. Also, no table locks until SQL is executed in one piece.

Bash will appear blocked. It is waiting for input to the pipe. To do it all from one bash instance, you can send the waiting process to the background instead. Like this:

```
postgres@db:~$ psql event -p5433 -f /tmp/myPipe 2>&1 &
```

---

Either way, from the same bash or a different instance, you can **fill the pipe** now.
Demo with three rows for variant **1)**:

```
postgres@db:~$ echo '1  foo' >> /tmp/myPipe; echo '2    bar' >> /tmp/myPipe; echo '3    baz' >> /tmp/myPipe;
```

(Take care to use tabs as delimiters or instruct [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html) to accept a different delimiter using `WITH DELIMITER 'delimiter_character'`)
That will trigger the pending psql with the COPY command to execute and return:

```
COPY 3
```

Demo for for variant **2)**:

```
postgres@db:~$ (echo -n "INSERT INTO x.x VALUES (1,'foo')" >> /tmp/myPipe; echo -n ",(2,'bar')" >> /tmp/myPipe; echo ",(3,'baz')" >> /tmp/myPipe;)

INSERT 0 3
```

Delete the named pipe after you are done:

```
postgres@db:~$ rm /tmp/myPipe
```

Check success:

```
event=# select * from x.x;
 id |         a
----+-------------------
  1 | foo
  2 | bar
  3 | baz
```

#### Useful links for the code above

[Reading compressed files with postgres using named pipes](http://www.ralree.com/2009/09/04/reading-compressed-files-with-postgres-using-named-pipes/)
[Introduction to Named Pipes](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156)
[Best practice to run bash script in background](http://www.unix.com/solaris/46427-best-practice-run-bash-script-background.html)

---

#### Advice you may or may not not need

For bulk `INSERT` you have better solutions than a separate [INSERT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html) per row. Use this syntax variant:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3) VALUES
 (1, 'foo', 'bar')
,(2, 'goo', 'gar')
,(3, 'hoo', 'har')
...
;
```

Write your statements to a file and do one mass `INSERT` like this:

```
psql -h remote_server -U username -d database -p 5432 -f my_insert_file.sql
```

(5432 or whatever port the db-cluster is listening on)
`my_insert_file.sql` can hold multiple SQL statements. In fact, it's common practise to restore / deploy whole databases like that. Consult the [manual about the **`-f`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html) parameter, or in bash: `man psql`.

Or, if you can transfer the (compressed) file to the server, you can use **[COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html)** to insert the (decompressed) data even faster.

You can also do some or all of the processing inside PostgreSQL. For that you can `COPY TO` (or `INSERT INTO`) a temporary table and use plain SQL statements to prepare and finally INSERT / UPDATE your tables. I do that a lot. Be aware that temporary tables live and die with the session.

You could use a GUI like [pgAdmin](http://pgadmin.org) for comfortable handling. A session in an SQL Editor window remains open until you close the window. (Therefore, temporary tables live until you close the window.)

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the party, but why couldn't you combine all your `INSERT` statements into a single string, with a semicolon marking the end of each statement? (Warning! Pseudocode ahead...)

Instead of:

```
for each line
  sql_statement="INSERT whatever YOU want"
  echo $sql_statement | psql ...
done
```

Use:

```
sql_statements=""
for each line
  sql_statement="INSERT whatever YOU want;"
  sql_statements="$sql_statements $sql_statement"
done
echo $sql_statements | psql ...
```

That way you don't have to create anything on your filesystem, do a bunch of redirection, run any tasks in the background, remember to delete anything on your filesystem afterwards, or even remind yourself what a named pipe is.