# PostgreSQL background session

Tags: linux, shell, postgresql

I work with an ancient inventory control application on Linux. It can only print to text files to communicate with other software. When I need to update a table in our PostgreSQL database I have been using `psql -f text_file` (where `text_file` is the file of SQL commands generated by our old application) This works fine but is rather slow as the psql session terminates after completing each text file. I was wondering if there is method of invoking a psql session as a background process that waits for input and does not terminate.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run a bunch of sql files against your database, one after the other, I would start up `psql` as interactive console:

```
psql mydatabase
```

And execute one file after the other with [the \i command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html):

```
\i text_file
```

---

If you want to script / automate things, a **fifo** might be what you need. I wrote [more about that here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7850704/939860).

Or you may be interested in a **coprocess** like [Craig Ringer describes here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8305578/939860).

Comment: Just curious, why is that preferable to just catting all of the files at once to `psql -f -`?

Comment: @TimPote: May be preferable if you want to check on the result of each file before you proceed or if the files have to be executed in a certain order or if not all of them are available at the same time or if the same file (with changed content) is used repeatedly. I wrote "one after the other" in my intro to refer to that.

Comment: Hi Erwin, thank you very much for this - it has solved my initial problem and been an education.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're wanting.  If you just have a bunch of files that need processing, use:

```
cat *.sql | psql -f -
```

If you are just wanting to continually run psql and have it run any changes in a file, something like this may work:

```
(   
while sleep 5; do
  print "\i sql_file.sql;"
  cat /dev/null > sql_file.sql
done
) | psql --file -
```

I'm not sure how advisable this is, I've never done it myself.

Comment: +1 The `cat` route should be the simplest solution if you just want to execute a bunch of file in no particular order and do not want to check the result in between.

Comment: Thanks Tim, the  allows me to genereate the SQL statements in the application and then pipe them out to the pseudo printer psql -f - this significantly reduces overhead.